# Why I can't resolve image with React Native

Tags: image, react-native, png, require

I'm trying to resolve image with the path name, but whatever I tried there's nothing workss well.

Here is the path way:

```
images
|  |
|  |
|  myImage.png
|   
components
   |
   UI
    |
    |_ _ SideBar.js
```

Here is the code inside the `SideBar.js`:

```
<ImageBackground source={require('../../images/myImage.png')} style={{ width: 200}}>
   <Text>Profile Card</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Comment: try to give height

Comment: also width '100%', just to make sure first if the image loaded or not

Comment: Sorry, but that was helpless

Comment: widht and height not works?

Comment: is ImageBackground as the outer element? or it wrapped inside another element such as View maybe?

Comment: First of all my Component must get the image and after that do some manipulations.
Yes it is wraped inside the main View.

Comment: then try to give width to the View

Comment: cause I've try your code and it works

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: could you please show more code? or what error you got?

Comment: Oh thank You for trying to help my, that was an individual problem thank You very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with just stoping and running my package again